# Check condition of Observable and execute/return function (angular2, rxjs)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to check the condition (is data is available in storage or get data from api) is true/false and then call the corresponding function which the result is passed on.

Now, i'm checking this in the component but I want to move this to the service side.

**service.ts**

```
getData() {
// check source of data to return...
   return this.hasLocal().subscribe((res) => {
        if (res === 0) // no data in storage
            return this.getRemote(); // <-- I want to return this
        else
            return this.getLocal(); // <-- or this to the component.
    })
}

getRemote() {
    console.log('getRemote()');
    return this.api.get(this.apiEndpoint).map(
        res => {
            let resJson = res.json();
            // save data to storage:
            this.storage.set(this.storageName, JSON.stringify(resJson))
                .then(() => console.log('Data saved in storage.'))
                .catch(() => console.warn('Error while saving data in storage.'));

            return resJson;
        });
}

getLocal() {
    console.log('getLocal()');
    let promise = this.storage.get(this.storageName).then(res => {
        return res;
    });
    return Observable.fromPromise(promise).map(res => {
        return JSON.parse(res);
    });
}

hasLocal() {
    let promise = this.storage.length().then(res => res);
    return Observable.fromPromise(promise).map(res => res);
}
```

`GetData()` is called in the component, and then the result is written to the array`contacts`.

**component.ts**

```
loadData() {
    this.contactsProvider.getData().subscribe(
        contacts => {
            console.log(contacts);
            this.initializeData(contacts);
            this.loader.dismiss();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. Sadly, I'm not very good at observables, but I think the here key is to one of the RxJs methods instead of a logical if statement in subscribe. There has to be something that handles this case using the reactive pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mergeMap`( `flatMap` is the rxjs4 alias) operator for this:

```
getData() {
// check source of data to return...
   return this.hasLocal().mergeMap((res) => {
        if (res === 0) // no data in storage
            return this.getRemote(); // <-- I want to return this
        else
            return this.getLocal(); // <-- or this to the component.
    })
}
```

`flatMap` documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap

You can import it with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';`